# How to disable onTap function when a single click has been clicked. Using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, vote-up-buttons

How to disable onTap function when a single click has been clicked. Using Flutter.

This is my code below, kindly help me check it out...

```dart
class VoteCalonUmumPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const VoteCalonUmumPage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  
  final String title;

  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return ListTile(
      tileColor: Color(0xff99c2ec),
      title: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Text(document['name'],
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  fontSize: 20,
                )),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xffecc399),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Text(
              document['votes'].toString(),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      onTap: () {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
          DocumentSnapshot freshSnap =
              await transaction.get(document.reference);
          await transaction.update(freshSnap.reference, {
            'votes': freshSnap['votes'] + 1,
          });
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout below code a simple logic it may help you ,

```
bool isLoading = false; //global variable

onTap: () {
if(!isLoading)
  {

    isLoading = true;
    try{
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        DocumentSnapshot freshSnap =  await transaction.get(document.reference);
        await transaction.update(freshSnap.reference, {'votes': freshSnap['votes'] + 1,});
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }catch((e){
      isLoading = false
    });
  }
},
```

Comment: If the author of the question wants not to use the stateful class, you can go for a singleton controller class that has an `isLoading` variable.

Comment: if using stateless class, this code doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

In order to actually disable the `onTap` handler you have to pass `null` to `onTap`. I would create a variable inside this class to keep track of if the `onTap` has been pressed yet, and if it has, pass `null` to `onTap` rather than your callback function.

```dart
onTap: onTapPressed ? null : () {
  setState(() {
    // call set state here so that the UI will be updated.
    onTapPressed = true;
  });
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
    DocumentSnapshot freshSnap =
    await transaction.get(document.reference);
    await transaction.update(freshSnap.reference, {
      'votes': freshSnap['votes'] + 1,
    });
  });
},
```

And then in your widget add this member.

```dart
bool onTapPressed = false;
```

---

Also `ListTile` also has an optional parameter called `enabled`, which you could set to `false` instead of passing `null` to `onTap`. This approach will disable all handlers on the `ListTile`, not just the `onTap` (you might also have an `onLongPress` handler for example). And it will also update the styling to use the `disabled` colors from the current `Theme`.

```dart
disabled: !onTapPressed,
onTap: () {
  setState(() {
    // call set state here so that the UI will be updated.
    onTapPressed = true;
  });
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
    DocumentSnapshot freshSnap =
    await transaction.get(document.reference);
    await transaction.update(freshSnap.reference, {
      'votes': freshSnap['votes'] + 1,
    });
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below code

`IgnorePointer` is a built-in widget in flutter which is similar to the AbsorbPointer widget, they both prevent their children’s widget from pointer-events which are taping, clicking, dragging, scrolling, and hover.IgnorePointer widget just ignores the pointer-events without terminating it, which means if there is any other element below the IgnorePointer widget tree then it will be able to experience that pointer-event.

```
bool disableOnClick = false;

IgnorePointer(
          ignoring: disableOnClick ?? false,
          child: ListTile(
            tileColor: Color(0xff99c2ec),
            title: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(document['name'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      )),
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xffecc399),
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    document['votes'].toString(),
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            onTap: () {
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
                DocumentSnapshot freshSnap =
                    await transaction.get(document.reference);
                await transaction.update(freshSnap.reference, {
                  'votes': freshSnap['votes'] + 1,
                });
              });
              disableOnClick = true;
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make condition like :-

set one bool variable and set it true and when user tap on button set it false if you want to permanently disable use prefrences

bool isClicked = true;

```
GestureDetector(
onTap:  (){
      if(isClicked){
        isClicked = true;
    enter code here
       }

   } 
  child: Container(),
)
```

Comment: u can use set state